# trying to install kivy on windows 8.1

Tags: python, pygame, cython, kivy

I'm trying to install kivy to make an application for android and ios.

I have installed the portable app as per the website but wanted to have it included in my python Idle.

So I searched and found Kivy-1.8.0.win32-py3.4.exe installs it ontop of your python instalation (C:\python34)

When i try and import i can import kivy but it wont let me install App or recognise UIX.

[image]

I have looked around and I think that my issue is with pygame, every time i try to install it i get missing files and that is with pip and a pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi that i found but still nothing!

Also read it might be cython and i installed that too downloading Cython-0.21.1 andtrying to run the instaltion on that.

Is there a way to get this done without a headache?

Do i need kivy to make an app for android and ios or can i use tkinter? (thats works on my pc lol)

please any advice would be great, I have searched but all the information out there is very disjointed and im hoping to find a one stop answer in one of you guys.

thanks

Raif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need kivy to make an app for android and ios or can i use tkinter? (thats works on my pc lol)

You need kivy (or maybe some other python tools, but I don't think any are remotely as good). The android build tools only work on linux or osx, though you can use a virtual machine for it.

If you installed from the popular unofficial windows binaries site, make sure the version matches your python version, and you probably need to get pygame from the same place. I don't know much about this though.

Comment: thanks yest i found that list and did all pygame then kivy and it now works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Linux is the best python development  environment. Python on Windows is very very buggy with certain packages due to compatibility issue.  Many important development packages in python are optimized for Linux.  You get rid of all headache by downloading and installing a lightweight Linux like o. So like back box on a virtual  machine.

Comment: Thanks yeah it might be worth looking into, but for now i'm just wondering about getting kivy to work or having a different method to output to android etc

Comment: I say do yourself a favour and just get linux. I switched from windows 7 to ubuntu, for development with python(and kivy) and it's really a relief!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is a Kivy app for iOS and Android, you have already made several mistakes. The first is that you cannot create an iOS app from any OS except OSX. There's no way around that. The second is that the tools for compiling for Android and iOS only work with Python2.7 currently. You seem to be using Python 3.4.

Comment: Is what in development? The ability to make iOS apps from any OS other than Apple? No. The ability to compile apps for mobile using Python3? Yes. The ability to compile Android apps on Windows? Not really.

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful and informative post! As can easily be gleaned by the post i was replying to stating i couldn't make an ios app, so yes i was referring to an android app! i don't think i was being vague! I'm glad that since learning python over the last week on my breaks at work the others I've asked for help were more helpful and less condescending!

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as condescending. When you type from a mobile device sometimes the niceties are dropped in favor of brevity.